# SQLAlchemy: ObjectNotExecuteableError on joins

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, select, sqlalchemy

I'm currently struggeling with a statement in SQLAlchemy. Basically the SQL script itself is working and looks like'

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3, t3.col1
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN t3 on t1.id = t3.id and t3.col2 = 12345
```

Now, splitting this statement into SQLAlchemy I've ended up with something like this:

```
stmt = select([t1.c.col1, t1.c.col2, t2.c.col1, t2.c.col2, t2.c.col3, t3.c.col1]).distinct().\
     select_from(table(t1)).\
     join(table(t2), t1.c.id == t2.c.id).\
     outerjoin(table(t3), and_((t1.c.id == t3.c.id), (t3.c.col2 == 12345))
```

I guess it's because of the distinct. I've also placed it at the end of the full line after outerjoin, but there I get an attribute error, saying that join has no attribute distinct.

Any hints on this for my?

Many thanks in advance, regards, Thomas

Comment: I also left out the distinct and tried to let it running without, the error remains the same, I get an ObjectNotExecutableError. I tried to get it printed, but `print(str(stmt))` returns another error: ` 'str' object has no attribute '_compiler_dispatch'`

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe it myself, but I've found the answer to my problem. It's more or less the way how joins have to be concatenated together.

The solution for my query above is:

```
stmt = select([t1.c.col1, t1.c.col2, t2.c.col1, t2.c.col2, t2.c.col3, t3.c.col1]).\
     select_from(
         table(t1).\
         join(table(t2), t1.c.id == t2.c.id).\
         outerjoin(table(t3), and_((t1.c.id == t3.c.id), (t3.c.col2 == 12345)))
     ).distinct()
```